# How to reset preferences in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC on Mac?

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe-reader, reset, default-settings

I would like to reset the preferences to default values in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC on Mac. I found the following discussions on Adobe forum but none of them was helpful:

1. [how do I reset Adobe Acrobat to the default settings?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2203739)

   - Adobe staff answered it and pointed to discussion 2 and 3; none of them worked.
2. [How do I reset Adobe to its original settings?](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-do-I-reset-Adobe-to-its-original-settings-q103963.aspx)

   - I tried to reinstall Reader DC per the answer's instruction but old preferences persisted after reinstallation.
3. [How to reset Preference settings in Acrobat.](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1595848)

   - The instructions were for Acrobat, not Acrobat Reader. I looked through my Library folder and found none of the folders/files mentioned.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

close acrobat reader and delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.adobe.Reader.plist`
then open it again, it should generate a new file (with fresh settings).